# How can I see the results of Sys.time() in HMS format and not decimal numbers?

Tags: r

In my R script when I want to calculate the running time of a function I use
'''
start <- Sys.time()
function
finish <- Sys.time()
difftime(finish, start)
'''
The answer that I get from these codes is: " Time difference of 6.60801 mins"
I want to see the time format in hours:minutes:seconds.
In other words: How can I get the following message as the response of running my codes? "Time difference of 6:36 mins"
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

We can use `as_hms` from the `hms` package.

library(hms)

```
start <- Sys.time() 
finish <- Sys.time() 

as_hms(difftime(finish, start))
# 00:00:00.00066
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some modular math and put it in a small function, e.g.:

```
HMS <- \(x) sprintf('%03d:%02d:%02d', x %/% 60^2, x %% 60^2 %/% 60, floor(x %% 60^2 %% 60))


t0 <- Sys.time()
t11 <- t0 + 6.60801*60
t12 <- t0 + 25*60^2 + 31*60 + 56.7398

HMS(as.numeric(difftime(t11, t0, units='secs')))
# [1] "000:06:36"

HMS(as.numeric(difftime(t12, t0, units='secs')))
# [1] "025:31:56"
```